# Using the relation as the query with Ember.Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

A user can have any number of `Foo` models, each referencing a `Bar` model, but not vice versa (the server doesn't return the other half data). The relation is 1 to 1.

Is it possible to perform a query to find the Foo model for a given Bar model?

I managed to get it work with filters:

```
this.store.find('foo', function(foo) {
  return foo.get('bar') === bar;
}).then(function(result) {
  foo = result.get('firstObject');
  ...
})
```

Although I'm not terribly happy with the length and syntax, and would rather prefer something along the lines of:

```
this.store.find('foo', {'bar': bar}).then(function(foo) { ... })
```

or at least

```
this.store.find('foo', {'bar.id': bar.get('id')}).then(function(foo) { ... })
```

neither of which work.

In this particular case, all relevant models are always loaded in the store, so there is no need to fetch data from the server.

Is it possible, that this issue may be related to the fact, that the JSON response doesn't have references from Bar to Foo, even though the query is in the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `FooAdapter`s `findQuery` method and add your own logic to handle looking up by `bar` property.

if you did something like this

```
App.FooAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  findQuery: function(store, type, query){
    if (query.bar) {
      return this.findAll(store, type).then(function(arr){
        return arr.filter(function(foo){
          return foo.bar == query.bar;
        });
      });
    }
    return [];//this can also be "return this._super();"
  }
});
```

then you would be able to do

```
this.store.find('foo', {bar: 1})
```

here is a working bin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bomoz/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, that certainly is an option. Do you happen to know, was there a reason, why this was omitted from Ember Data?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how you would expect it to work. But if you pass an object in as the second param it currently serializes the object to a querystring and passes it along with the request. In your case you said that you would always have all the data that you need in the browser so you can just define `findQuery` as I did above to intercept the request and return the items from the store.

Comment: I meant, why is the above implementation not the one used in Ember Data – i.e. is there a design decision to avoid such queries or it's just not implemented yet